# Getting in different format the date cells content in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I create the following code to get the cells content in Apache POI by Java language for a project.

I have a file.xls that submits to this code. I want to know if it could possible to obtain, in the output, the dates present in the cells in different format, not extended like this Tue Apr 21 00:00:00 BST 2015, but simply: 21/04/2015, how can do that?

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFDateUtil;

public class Readsheet 
{
   static HSSFRow row;
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
   {
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
      new File("test2.xls"));
      HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
      HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
      Iterator < Row > rowIterator = spreadsheet.iterator();
      while (rowIterator.hasNext()) 
      {
         row = (HSSFRow) rowIterator.next();
         Iterator < Cell > cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         while ( cellIterator.hasNext()) 
         {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
            switch (cell.getCellType()) 
            {


               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                   if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                       System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue());
                   } else {
                       System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                   }

               break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
               System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + " \t\t " );
               break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
               System.out.println(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                   break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
                   System.out.println(cell.getCellFormula() + " \t\t ");
                   break;
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
                   System.out.println();
                   break;

            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
      fis.close();
   }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following code -

```
String cellValue = new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
```

It will give you `cell` value in `cellValue` variable in the same format which is specified in excel file. So, in excel file, if your date is show as dd/MM/yyyy format, you will get in the same format in code.

Comment: I use the code instead of what?
I did so:  
`switch (cell.getCellType()) 
            {
            
            
               case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                
                new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell);
                if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                       System.out.println(cell.getDateCellValue() +  " \t\t ");
                   } else {
                       System.out.println(cell.getNumericCellValue() + " \t\t ");
                   }`

Comment: Ok I understand, I have put that:
'System.out.println(new DataFormatter().formatCellValue(cell) +  " \t\t ");'
and now the code works correctly!
Thank you very much :)

Comment: @Lost_in_the_code I have updated the answer for removing your doubt. If it solved your question, approve the answer.